# cheerio javascript тег li разбивает тег p

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, cheerio

Почему так происходит?

```
let $ = cheerio.load('<p>Обычный текст<li></li> продолжение текста</p>', {decodeEntities: false});
$('p').each(function (i, attr) {
  let html = $(attr).html();
  console.log(html);
});
//Обычный текст
```

А если так:

```
let $ = cheerio.load('<p>Обычный текст<strong></strong> продолжение текста</p>', {decodeEntities: false});
$('p').each(function (i, attr) {
  let html = $(attr).html();
  console.log(html);
});
//Обычный текст<strong></strong> продолжение текста
```

Comment: Теги <li>, у которых ближайший родитель не является <ul> или <ol> не валидны. Не знаю, как с cheerio, но пару раз натыкался на баги из-за этого. Сохраняйте правильную структуру html-разметки, ибо для парсера браузера это может быть проблемой, а в вашем случае, для модуля cheerio.

Comment: С этим у меня все правильно. Это просто как пример `<p>Обычный текст<ol><li></li></ol> продолжение текста</p>` в таком варианте результат тоже "Обычный текст"-(

Comment: Внутри <p></p> не может быть блочных элементов

Comment: А даже так...Этого я не знал, может и правда причина в этом..

Comment: Отрисовка различных элементов страницы называется потоком. Если в блочных элементах могут находится inline-элементы, то блочные внутри инлайнов нарушают поток.